# How to use like in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to filter a form based on the value in a combo box. Also I want to be able to filter the form base on the value entered in the combo box. like if I type something partially in the combo box I want the form to show all records in the guyname field that contains the types word in the combo box. But I cant seem to make it work.

```
Me.Filter = "[Guyname] ='" & Me.Combo21 & "'" & " AND [guyID] = '" & Me.Combo36 & "'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: Doesn't look like you're trying to use LIKE in your example. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
DoCmd.ApplyFilter , "guyName like '" & me.combo21 & "*'"
```

You get the idea...
Don't forget the strange comma. Providing a criteria string is the second parameter.

Comment: Thank you sir, I used your idea to modify my code and it worked. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This also helped me a great deal so I thought I would add into this the code for Filters re Numeric , Date and Text filters all of which depend on the use of single , double quotes or # to get the Filter Criteria correct.

```
Numeric Field Filter Setting
strFilter = "[DebitAccount] = " & Me.[Cbo-dbLedgerAcc]
***
Date Range Filter Setting
strsearchEntryDate = Format(CDate(Me.[Txt-EntryDate]), "mm/dd/yyyy")
     strFilter = "[DebitEntryDate] = #" & strsearchEntryDate & "# "
     strFilter = strFilter & "Or " & "[CreditEntryDate] =  #" & strsearchEntryDate & "# "
Text Filter Setting 
Dim Searchstring as string
SearchString = Me.[txt-DetString]    
Option 1 Complete Text Match 
   strFilter = "MatchDescription = '" & Me.[txt-DetString] & "'"
Option 2 Word / Text Match  
    strFilter = "[MatchDescription] Like '*" & SearchString & "*'"
***
Me.Filter = strFilter
Me.FilterOn = True
'** Helpful to also Order Filter Results
Me.OrderBy = "MatchDescription Desc"
Me.OrderByOn = True
```

Answer (score 0):

In a query:

```
Where [LastName] Like "*" & forms!FormName!ControlName & "*"
The form must be open when the query is run.
```

On a form to filter the form?

Code the AfterUpdate event of the control:

```
Me.Filter = "[LastName] Like '*" & [ControlName] & "*'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

These filters will return records that have the text anywhere within the
field.